# I am finding it difficult to understand this adjacency matrix property- graph theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The following properties I am having difficulty with

Let G be a graph with vertices v <sub>1</sub>, v <sub>2</sub> , ..., v<sub>n</sub>  and let A = a<sub>i,j</sub> be the adjacency matrix of G.

- The diagonal entries of A are all 0; that is, a <sub>i i</sub>  = 0 for i = 1,...,n.
- The adjacency matrix is symmetric, that is a  <sub>i j</sub>   = a <sub>j i</sub>   for all i, j. 
  degv <sub>i</sub>  i is the number of 1’s in row i; this is also the number of 1’s in column i (row  <sub>i</sub> and column  <sub>i</sub>   are the same)

I do not get these properties:

The $(i,j)$ entry of $A^2$ is the number of diﬀerent walks of length $2$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$, in particular, the degree of $v_i$ is the ith main diagonal entry of $A^2$.

In general, for any $k\gt  1$, the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^k$ is the number of walks of length $k$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$.

**so..
If I have a triangle graph with 
vertices = v1, v2 , v3**

And Adjacency matrix 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\text{ then }A^2=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 & 1\\1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

**then the property** 
 $(i,j)$ entry of $A^2$ is the number of diﬀerent walks of length $2$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$, in particular, the degree of $v_i$ is the ith main diagonal entry of $A^2$.

means that from v<sub>1</sub> to v<sub>1</sub> the number of different walks with length two is **2**?

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: Can you write down the formula for matrix multiplication?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.  Note that you have to $ signs around the formulas for the formatting to show up.

Comment: What is $A$? What is Ak? Do you mean $A^k$?

Comment: yes I did sorry

Comment: Ah, so $A_{ij}$ is the number of walks of length 1 from $v_i$ to $v_j$ (probably meaning that $v_i$ and $v_j$ are adjacent in the graph). Things are slowly making more sense. I assume that all edges in the graph have length 1? Please ask the question in a way so that the reader does not have to derive any important property on his/her own.

Comment: Also, I would assume that the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^k$ is the number of different walks of length $\leq k$, right? As saulspatz already suggested, the property will become clearer if you write down the formula for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231841/powers-of-adjacency-matrix-determination-of-connection-in-graph/231854, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527204/if-a-is-the-adjacency-matrix-of-a-graph-why-does-the-i-j-entry-of-an-g

Comment: Have you tried drawing your example graph and counting walks explicitly?

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering, I get it now after reading it several times. It is basically just saying that k is equal to the length of walks. so if K = 2, then the length of walks is two, if K=3 then length of walks is 3 so length of walks can be less or greater than k.